# Safari plugin rejected by Apple: "does not use a custom icon"

Tags: plugins, safari

My team has attempted several submissions of a Safari Plug-in to Apple and have been rejected with the following message:

> "Thank you for submitting your extension [name removed] to be
>   considered for a listing on the Safari Extensions Gallery. During
>   review, we discovered that your extension does not use a custom icon.
>   For instructions on how to use a custom icon for your extension,
>   please see the Safari Extensions Development Guide. Please investigate
>   and address this issue, then resubmit your extension so that it can be
>   reviewed and considered for a listing on the Safari Extensions
>   Gallery."

We've read the Safari Extensions Development guide several times and believe we are submitting correctly.  Does any one have any experience receiving and then overcoming this error who might be able to provide some guidance?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Just got it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured this one out Sean. You should have the following icons (with the exact name you see) in your `Info.plist` directory:

[image]